# How to return 401 in flask despite authorization

Tags: python-3.x, flask, http-status-code-401

I am new to flask and I want to return 401 error, I am not using authentication, I am simply using a parameter api_key to check whether the user is authenticated.
I've tried `abort(401)` and `return false`, but it returns error 400 'Bad Request', is this the default way it returns a 401. Or is there a different way to do this?

My Code:

```py
import flask
from flask import jsonify, request, Response
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
googlenews = GoogleNews()
googlenews.set_lang('en')
googlenews.set_period('1d')
googlenews.set_encode('utf-8')   
app=flask.Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
@cross_origin()
@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def return_news():
    API_KEY = request.args['api_key']
    if API_KEY == "xyz":
        googlenews.get_news('TECHNOLOGY')
        return jsonify(googlenews.result(True)[0:4])
    else:
        return Response(response="Unauthorized", status=401)
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 4):

instead, try `flask.Response` object.

```py
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/abort")
def abort():
    return Response(response="Unauthorized", status=401)


app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

without the actual code it is hard to tell, but I think it is not using the flask abort() but the python  internal abort() function.

Check the code below:

```py
import flask
app = flask.Flask("aborter")

@app.route("/abort")
def abort():
    return flask.abort(401)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Happy Coding